# sem:sparql binding property path

Tags: sparql, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am looking to do a simple SPARQL query using variable property paths.  Something like

```
sem:sparql("SELECT ?o WHERE { </person/10025613.xml> <hasManager>+ ?o . }")
```

That query works fine.  But now when I want to make the statement work with variables, I cannot get it to syntax check correctly.

```
sem:sparql("
  SELECT   ?o WHERE { ?s ?p+ ?o . }
", $params)
```

...results in an unexpected token syntax.  Also, I tried

```
let $params := map:new(
  (
    map:entry("s", sem:iri("/person/10025613.xml")),
    map:entry("p", concat(sem:iri("hasManager"), "+"))
  )
)
```

Which does not work either. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

SPARQL property paths explicitly do not allow variables. See [SPARQL 1.1 Property Paths](http://w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths).

You can follow paths with variables by following object properties.  For example:

```sql
SELECT ?o
WHERE {
   ?s ?p ?o1 .
   ?o1 ?p1 ?o .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are situations in which you may want to assign several values to a SPARQL property path without rewriting the entire string. This is possible with SPARQL implementations that allow namespaces to be defined at runtime.

For example: `rdflib` is a python package for working with RDF graphs, and includes a plugin for SPARQL query execution. Namespaces may be defined at runtime, allowing us to define a variable property path (where the variable is bound) using the following hack:

```
SELECT ?s ?o
WHERE {
    ?s p:+ ?o .
}
```

The namespace `p:` is not defined in the query. Instead, at runtime we can specify which path we desire, e.g. with `rdflib`:

```py
from rdflib import Graph, URIRef

Graph().query(
    query_string,
    initNs={
        "p": URIRef("https://www.example.com/your_predicate")
    }
```

This doesn't help people that desire to have a variable path, but may help those that wish to leverage the expressiveness of property paths on bound variables without breaking the SPARQL syntax rules.

I would imagine that this is dangerous behavior and should only be used with caution. Anyone who can provide a solid reason why this is against SPARQL rules will earn a +1.